# Is there a way to create an organization dashboard in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

Our team is currently using DevOps and are very pleased with how everything is working. We've setup Dashboards in each project that tracks work items and sprints and would like to do the same at the Organization Level. Is there a way to create a master overview of multiple projects in an organization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot create an organization level dashboard, it's not supported.

We can only create the Team Project level dashboards for teams, please see [Add and manage dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/dashboards?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) for details.

However there's already a [user voice submitted here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365500/single-dashboard-for-multiple-projects.html) to suggest the feature and it's in planned, but based on the response seems no plans to store a dashboard on organization overview. So you can vote it up and add your comments on the existing user voice or submit a new one to suggest the feature...

> In our VSTS Feature
> Timeline(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/), you
> see a feature called “Dashboards – Create dashboard separate from a
> team” under “Reporting”
>
> This feature will allow you to create a Dashboard that has no
> association with the team. This means you don’t need to create a team,
> to make a Dashboard. You can create any number of these Dashboards and
> share them with who you want.
>
> However, Dashboards will still be stored with a Team Project. So to
> address your scenario (cross-team-project Dashboard), you’ll just have
> to pick a team project to store the dashboard.
>
> We don’t have immediate plans to store a dashboard outside a team
> project.

Comment: The user voice link was dead when I clicked it.
Luckily, another thread opened up over here about it:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365500/single-dashboard-for-multiple-projects.html

Comment: Please up vote on the community request [Single Dashboard for Multiple Projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/single-dashboard-for-multiple-projects/365500).  In the meantime to solve the single team, multiple project board issue there is a free extension in the Marketplace although not perfect that can help... [Query Based Boards](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.EdTro-AzureDevOps-Extensions-QueryBasedBoards-Public&targetId=fdc1edee-e433-4373-ac8a-a4f42f8f153f&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList)

Answer (score 1):

Our team was dealing with the same problem as yours, and we decided to develop our own dashboard solution at the end.

After using it as an internal tool for several months, we recently made it available as a SaaS.

You may check it out on [meercode.io](https://meercode.io) for more information.

Your feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the dashboard widgets are queries, and it is possible to execute those queries across multiple projects.

When you open the query editor, there is a checkbox:
["Query across projects" checkbox (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIpsA.png)

This way we created a project in Devops that only contains a dashboard that shows all work items in any project, assigned to or followed by the current user.

That and some nifty colored tiles =)