# Azure Pipelines Widget/Report to View Pipeline Status Across Projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Does this exist?

I have 10 team projects in Azure DevOps, each with 2 to 5 pipelines (using multi-stage yaml pipelines, not classic Release pipelines).

Is there any widget or built in functionality to see a dashboard of all of my pipelines across all projects with red/green status? Thinking to create a PowerBI report if not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dashboards are specific to the Team Project. There still is no such thing as an Organization level dashboard (See earlier questions: [Is there a way to create an organization dashboard in Azure DevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728160/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-organization-dashboard-in-azure-devops))

The current "User Voice" topic for this request is here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365500/single-dashboard-for-multiple-projects.html

The best option outside of Power BI is creating a dashboard per team and then tagging each as a favorite. They are then accessible via the favorites shortcut in the top navigation.

[image: top nav example]